# Combobox selection to text file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

Newbie here so apologies for sounding dumb

I have a combobox that the user selects a value and clicks a submit button
I have no idea how to take the selected value and write it to a text file.
Is there anyone who can help?

thanks in advance... Jimbob

Comment: PLEASE Explain your question in more detail, like do you want to write the selected value of drop down in existing text file or u want to create a new text file ?

Comment: @RohitVyas I don't really think that this matters. The file will automatically be created if you try to write the text to a file that does not exist. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
    string PathToFile = "c:\\File.txt";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(PathToFile,Combobox.SelectValue.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks  Carlos - I need to value to go to a text file and not into a text box

Comment: THanks again Carlos :) Nearly there - Im getting the following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: This is because the combobox is not properly loaded and ComboBoxSelectedValue is null. Try writing   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(PathToFile,"HELLO"); and if the file is created then you must load your combo items properly

Comment: Thanks Carlos - THis worked perfectly.  One last question - How do I prevent it from overwriting each time and just append whats already in the text file?

Comment: You can use System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, content);

Comment: Again that worked but throws up one last question ! ( I promise) It adds the text side by side , I need it to be on a new line?

Comment: You want the text to continue on the same line you mean?

Comment: no the text to be on the next line.  This is what I have at the moment
abcd
what i need is
a
b
c
d

make sense?

Comment: Use this: System.IO.File.AppendAllText("c:\\File.txt", Environment.NewLine + text);

Comment: MAny thanks for your help today Carlos.  It really was kind of you to take the time to help me out

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, and me assuming you are not using MVVM, I'd think that you'll need a few things in place to make this happen:

1. Give your combo box a name in your XAML like: Name="myComboBox"
2. Also in XAML, add a Click event to your button
3. In the click handler for the button, write something like:  System.IO.File.WriteAllText("selected.txt", myComboBox.SelectedValue);

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that this question is about WPF. Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks Ray - Carlos code works perfectly fo rme.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You may detect the selected value of a `ComboBox` using `comboBox1.SelectedValue` which returns an object. If required, you may then convert it to string using `ToString()`

**Example**

```
string _string = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

This will initialize a new variable of name `_string` as the selected `ComboBox` value in `String`. You may also use `comboBox1.SelectedIndex` which returns an `int` to get the selected index of the item considering that `comboBox1` is a `ComboBox`.

Moreover, if you would like to write the value to a particular file, you may use `StreamWriter` or `File.WriteAllLines` but I believe that a `StreamWriter` will be more easier to manage

**Example**

```
string DestinationFile = @"D:\Resources\International\MyNewFile.txt"; //Initializes a new string of name DestinationFile as D:\Resources\International\MyNewFile.txt
StreamWriter _StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(DestinationFile); //Initializes a new StreamWriter class of name _StreamWriter
_StreamWriter.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); //Attempts to write the selected combo box value in string as a new line
_StreamWriter.Close(); //Closes the file and saves settings
```

**Notice**: This will create a new file at D:\Resources\International\MyNewFile.txt. Then, **overwrites** the file with a new line with the selected `ComboBox` item. If you would like to **append** the text to a particular file, you may want to add `,true` after `_StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(DestinationFile`

**Example**

```
string DestinationFile = @"D:\Resources\International\MyNewFile.txt"; //Initializes a new string of name DestinationFile as D:\Resources\International\MyNewFile.txt
StreamWriter _StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(DestinationFile, true); //Initializes a new StreamWriter class of name _StreamWriter
_StreamWriter.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); //Attempts to write the selected combo box value in string as a new line
_StreamWriter.Close(); //Closes the file and saves settings
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: thanks Picrofo - Very helpful - A little too complex for me at the moment but gives me great pointers to go off and develop my knowledge - Thank you for taking the time to answer my cry for help !

Comment: @jimbob--arooney I'm glad you had your issue resolved. Have a great day :)